# SUM of rows in My Sql with condition

Tags: mysql, sum

My Data is

```
ID       SCORE
 1        55
 1        -1
 1        25
 1        -1
 1        -1
 1        35
 2        25
 2        -1 
 2        65
 2        55
 2        21
 2        -1
```

Now i want to add/sum the score of each id ignoring -1 and i am trying with this code which is not working

```
SELECT SUM(CASE when SCORE>-1 THEN SUM(SCORE) ELSE 0 END) 
FROM jbit WHERE htno='$id'
```

Here i am already using WHERE so how can i use another WHERE, if i use multiple Where in single query it may effect other processes.. please help me out

Help me out friends

Comment: What do you expect as result? One row wih `sum=281` or two rows with `(1, 115), (2,166)`?

Comment: Check my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is only two column then there is no need to use SUM, you can try below

```
SELECT id, IF(SCORE=-1,0,SCORE) AS scoreSum
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a50/27)

alternative ( not tested )

```
SELECT id, SUM(IF(SCORE=-1,0,SCORE)) AS scoreSum
FROM table1
WHERE htno =$id
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: it is wrking but how to print d position of ID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS score_sum
FROM jbit 
WHERE htno='$id'
  AND score <> -1 ;
```

Comment: if there is a row  with `(4,-1)` then output will not have a row with value of 4 and sum = 0

Comment: @diEcho: It will be ignored. What do you mean?

Comment: but OP want if there is only one row having -1 then sum should be 0 for that row.

Comment: I assumed he wants one result only, the total sum of all rows. I can be wrong though :)

Comment: $SQL1 = "SELECT SUM(em) AS ext
FROM jbit 
WHERE htno='$id'
  AND score <> '-1'";
  $result4 = mysql_query($SQL1);
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
   echo "<td align=center>" . $row1['ext']. "</td>";
  }      Getting error (Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\man1.php on line 56)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`SCORE`)
FROM `jbit`
WHERE `htno` = '$id'
    `SCORE` > 0;
```

Though, I'd suggest you to change `'$id'` to just `$id` if the column type of `htno` is `INTEGER`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(score) FROM <tablename> WHERE score != -1
```